# DynamicJasper: how to control text wrapping in column

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

DynamicJasper attempts to wrap text when size of column is smaller than the size of text. The wrapping index, I believe,  is derived from the size of the column.
Is it possible to control the position of wrap?

For Example: I have a field which indicates time duration, say 04:00-04:30. The size of column determines the wrapping point after second `:`.

Is it possible to specify wrapping position for every column? Something like this:

```
col1.setWrapTextAfter("-",index)
```

or if the text is 23,45,**12**,6,77,9  (here it wraps after **"1"** sending **"2"** to next line!)

```
col2.setWrapTextAfter(",",anyindex)
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe for correcting my post, really appreciate it. Those are suggestions not actual  codes. DynamicJasper does not have those methods yet, I searched internet and am yet to find something useful.